# Added spaces and LRs in JSON via Appmaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm working in AppMaker to create a new employee/user provisioning workflow. I'm at the point where I am creating a new G Suite user, and I have a very weird problem with spaces in my JSON. It's leading to an error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.insert failed with error:

> Invalid Input at provisionUser (AdminDirectory:5)

I've been troubleshooting this for a while, and it seems that somewhere between AppMaker and the AdminDirectory call, some extra spaces and hard returns are inserted into my user data. Below I'm going to show:

1. The client-side code for gathering user information
2. The server-side user creation script
3. The console output of the user JSON
4. The output of the user JSON that comes to my email for troubleshooting
5. The emailed output as seen in Notepad++

*Client-Side Code*

```
...a bunch of data gathering from a form, then...
  var user = {
    primaryEmail: email,
    name: {
      givenName: firstName,
      familyName: lastName
    },
    addresses: [{
      type: 'work',
      formatted: address
    }],
    organizations: [{
      title: title,
      department: department,
      fullTimeEquivalent: ftpt
    }],
    phones: [{
      type: 'work',
      value: phone
    }],
    locations: [{
      buildingId: building,
      type: 'desk',
      area: 'desk'
    }],
    password: 'xxxxxxxx',
    changePasswordAtNextLogin: true,
    orgUnitPath: orgUnit,
    relations: [{
      type: 'manager',
      value: supervisor
    }],
    customSchemas: {
      sclsnj: {
        startDate: effective,
        mls: mls,
        location: location
      }
    }
  };
  google.script.run.provisionUser(user, grouparray);
```

*Server-Side Code*

```
function provisionUser(user, grouparray) {
  user = JSON.stringify(user);
  MailApp.sendEmail('lhoffman@xxxxxxxx.org', 'New Google User', user); 
  console.log(user);
  user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
  for (var g = 0; g < grouparray.length; g++) {
    var groupEmail = grouparray[g] + '@xxxxxxxx.org';
    var member = {
      email: user,
      role: 'MEMBER'
    };
    Logger.log(groupEmail);
    AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  }  
}
```

*Console Output*

```
{"primaryEmail":"jsmith@xxxxxxxx.org","name":{"givenName":"John","familyName":"Smith"},"addresses":[{"type":"work","formatted":"Bound Brook branch\n402 E High Street, Bound Brook, NJ 08805"}],"organizations":[{"title":"Library Technician","department":"Adult Services","fullTimeEquivalent":100000}],"phones":[{"type":"work","value":"908-458-8410"}],"locations":[{"buildingId":"BBROOK","type":"desk","area":"desk"}],"password":"xxxxxxxx","changePasswordAtNextLogin":true,"orgUnitPath":"/Branches/Bound Brook branch","relations":[{"type":"manager","value":"msmith@xxxxxxxx.org"}],"customSchemas":{"sclsnj":{"startDate":"2019-05-20T04:00:00.000Z","mls":false,"location":"Bound Brook branch"}}}
```

*Email Output*

```
{"primaryEmail":"jsmith@xxxxxxxx.org","name":{"givenName":"John","familyName":"Smith"},"addresses":[{"type":"work","formatted":"Bound  
Brook  
branch\n402 E High Street, Bound Brook, NJ  
08805"}],"organizations":[{"title":"Library Technician","department":"Adult  
Services","fullTimeEquivalent":100000}],"phones":[{"type":"work","value":"908-458-8410"}],"locations":[{"buildingId":"BBROOK","type":"desk","area":"desk"}],"password":"xxxxxxxx","changePasswordAtNextLogin":true,"orgUnitPath":"/Branches/Bound  
Brook  
branch","relations":[{"type":"manager","value":"msmith@xxxxxxxx.org"}],"customSchemas":{"sclsnj":{"startDate":"2019-05-20T04:00:00.000Z","mls":false,"location":"Bound  
Brook branch"}}}
```

*Email Output in Notepad++ (with control characters)*

[image: Output with Control Characters.jpg]

NOTE: I realize the JSON is actually represented in the image twice, but you can definitely see the extra space and left feed characters there.

I've confirmed that I can provision a user with the console output by using the Google API Explorer and copying and pasting it into the request body for the Directory API Users.insert.

I've also confirmed that the emailed version of the output does *not* work using the same method. When I paste that version into the request body in the API Explorer, I get an error alert and it's clear from the color-coding in the body field that it is not correct. Even when I don't email the output to myself, I get the same error behavior, so I'm pretty sure that the act of emailing isn't messing things up.

Help!!

Comment: Can you try logging the formatted address before you assign it to the 'user' object? It's a string and you can pull it straight out of the `address` field without the json.stringify() conversion. If it's still messed up then it's coming from the form rather than the code you've got here. You could write a simple function to strip the LRs and dual-spaces then pass the formatted address to that. Also, it's interesting to note that your notepad version has double spaces, whereas the console output doesn't.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Right? And the extra space is only where those pesky LFs show up.

Comment: @EngineerDollery The extra spaces aren't limited to the address (see department. orgUnitPath, location), or to the break in the location name (see the zip code). But here's the logged address: 

Bound Brook branch 402 E High Street, Bound Brook, NJ 08805

Comment: @Morfinismo Thanks for pulling out that error message for clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid input is a result of a specific field not correclty formatted. In your case, I see that you are using custom schemas. There is a specific filed in the custom schema that is not properly formatted, that is **startDate**. Instead of providing the value of **2019-05-20T04:00:00.000Z**, just use **2019-05-20**.

The reason for that is because the field is expecting a **complete date only** value instead of a **complete date plus hours and minutes**. As you can see on the [ISO-8601 date format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), the **complete date** format is **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/schemas/insert

Comment: Good catch?  I would have never seen that without you pointing it out.  Thanks.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I was so hung up on the extra LFs that I didn't even look at that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. How is this a correct answer to a spurious LF problem?

Comment: @EngineerDollery This is not the answer to the LF problem, this is the answer to the `Invalid Input at provisionUser (AdminDirectory:5)` error. OP thought the problem generated was caused by the LF when in fact it was the wrong formatting of a specific field. The only way to know what was wrong was to analyze every bit of information provided.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do it this way?

```
function provisionUser(user, grouparray) {
  var user = JSON.stringify(user);
  MailApp.sendEmail('lhoffman@xxxxxxxx.org', 'New Google User', user); 
  console.log(user);
  AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
  for (var g = 0; g < grouparray.length; g++) {
    var groupEmail = grouparray[g] + '@xxxxxxxx.org';
    var member = {
      email: user,
      role: 'MEMBER'
    };
    Logger.log(groupEmail);
    AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I'm still seeing the same output in both the email and the console as outlined in the question.